# Bug in canvas class in chart js

Tags: javascript, reactjs, canvas, chart.js

I'm using chart js-2 in a react project and i'm facing a bug which by inspecting element i show that it is a canvas bug. Let me explain.

This class:
`<canvas height="200" width="200" style="display: block; height: 250px; width: 250px;"></canvas>`   has these heights: 200px and 250px.

I use pie charts in three different pages. When i first render the pies the heights are zero. My first thought was that the data wasn't rendered but finally it did. Why is this happening?

Answer (score 1):

I found the solution, i must add the redraw property= true